# Работа с input и button

Tags: javascript, html5

Я создал простенький калькулятор, когда ввожу два числа с клавиатуры в два разных , то при нажатии на деление, умножение, сложение и вычитание, все срабатывает и выводиться в отдельное окошко Output. Так же я создал отдельные кнопки от 0 до 9. Хочу чтобы при выборе первого поля для ввода, и нажатии на кнопки 0-9, они вводились в данную форму. То же самое для второго поля, когда оно выбрано(второе поле), можно было вводить числа 0-9 не с клавиатуры.

```js
    function reset() {
        var res1 = document.getElementById('out');
        var res2 = document.getElementById('n1');
        var res3 = document.getElementById('n2');
        res1.value = '';
        res2.value = '';
        res3.value = '';
    }
    
    
    function plus() {
        var num1, num2, result;
        num1 = document.getElementById('n1').value;
        num1 = parseInt(num1);
        
        num2 = document.getElementById('n2').value;
        num2 = parseInt(num2);
        
        result = num1 + num2;
        
        document.getElementById('out').value = result;
        
    }
    
    function minus() {
        var num1, num2, result;
        num1 = document.getElementById('n1').value;
        num1 = parseInt(num1);
        
        num2 = document.getElementById('n2').value;
        num2 = parseInt(num2);
        
        result = num1 - num2;
        document.getElementById('out').value = result;
        
    }
    
    function multiply() {
        var num1, num2, result;
        num1 = document.getElementById('n1').value;
        num1 = parseInt(num1);
        
        num2 = document.getElementById('n2').value;
        num2 = parseInt(num2);
        
        result = num1 * num2;
        document.getElementById('out').value = result;
        
    }
    
    function divide() {
        var num1, num2, result;
        num1 = document.getElementById('n1').value;
        num1 = parseInt(num1);
        
        num2 = document.getElementById('n2').value;
        num2 = parseInt(num2);
        
        result = num1 / num2;
        document.getElementById('out').value = result;
        
    }
    
    function numBr() {
        
    }
    
    function onFocus() {
        
    }
```

```html
        <div id='first'>
    <hr> 
        <input type="text" id='n1' value='' placeholder='First number...' onclick='onFocus()'>
        <input type="text" id='n2' value='' placeholder='Second number' onclick='onFocus1'>
    <hr>
    <br>
        <button onclick="plus()">Plus +</button>
        <button onclick="minus()">Minus -</button>
        <button onclick="multiply()">Multiply *</button>
        <button onclick="divide()">Divide /</button>
        <button onclick="reset()">Clear</button>
    <hr>
    <br>
        <input type='text' id='out' value='' disabled='true' placeholder='Output...'>
    <hr>
    <br>
        <input type='button' onclick='numBr()' value='0'>
        <input type='button' onclick='numBr()' value='1'>
        <input type='button' onclick='numBr()' value='2'>
        <input type='button' onclick='numBr()' value='3'>
        <input type='button' onclick='numBr()' value='4'>
        <input type='button' onclick='numBr()' value='5'>
        <input type='button' onclick='numBr()' value='6'>
        <input type='button' onclick='numBr()' value='7'>
        <input type='button' onclick='numBr()' value='8'>
        <input type='button' onclick='numBr()' value='9'>
    <hr>     
        </div>
```

Comment: Нужен просто слушатель на нажатие кнопки, когда нажимаете на кнопку, в поле ввода нужно `+=` значение нажатой кнопки (0-9) Как сделать слушатель, и добавлять текст в поле, все это есть в достатке везде и всюду, море статей, обучающих материалов, и документаций. <br>
Например: <br> Значение поля = ""; *нажатие кнопки* { Значение поля += кнопка.value; }

Answer (score 1):

```js
function reset() {
        var res1 = document.getElementById('out');
        var res2 = document.getElementById('n1');
        var res3 = document.getElementById('n2');
        res1.value = '';
        res2.value = '';
        res3.value = '';
    }


    function plus() {
        var num1, num2, result;
        num1 = document.getElementById('n1').value;
        num1 = parseInt(num1);

        num2 = document.getElementById('n2').value;
        num2 = parseInt(num2);

        result = num1 + num2;

        document.getElementById('out').value = result;

    }

    function minus() {
        var num1, num2, result;
        num1 = document.getElementById('n1').value;
        num1 = parseInt(num1);

        num2 = document.getElementById('n2').value;
        num2 = parseInt(num2);

        result = num1 - num2;
        document.getElementById('out').value = result;

    }

    function multiply() {
        var num1, num2, result;
        num1 = document.getElementById('n1').value;
        num1 = parseInt(num1);

        num2 = document.getElementById('n2').value;
        num2 = parseInt(num2);

        result = num1 * num2;
        document.getElementById('out').value = result;

    }

    function divide() {
        var num1, num2, result;
        num1 = document.getElementById('n1').value;
        num1 = parseInt(num1);

        num2 = document.getElementById('n2').value;
        num2 = parseInt(num2);

        result = num1 / num2;
        document.getElementById('out').value = result;

    }


    var field;

    function numBr(num) {
      field.value = field.value + num.value;
    }

    function onFocus(field_) {
      field = field_;
    }
```

```html
<div id='first'>
    <hr>
        <input type="text" id='n1' value='' placeholder='First number...' onclick='onFocus(this)'>
        <input type="text" id='n2' value='' placeholder='Second number' onclick='onFocus(this)'>
    <hr>
    <br>
        <button onclick="plus()">Plus +</button>
        <button onclick="minus()">Minus -</button>
        <button onclick="multiply()">Multiply *</button>
        <button onclick="divide()">Divide /</button>
        <button onclick="reset()">Clear</button>
    <hr>
    <br>
        <input type='text' id='out' value='' disabled='true' placeholder='Output...'>
    <hr>
    <br>
        <input type='button' onclick='numBr(this)' value='0'>
        <input type='button' onclick='numBr(this)' value='1'>
        <input type='button' onclick='numBr(this)' value='2'>
        <input type='button' onclick='numBr(this)' value='3'>
        <input type='button' onclick='numBr(this)' value='4'>
        <input type='button' onclick='numBr(this)' value='5'>
        <input type='button' onclick='numBr(this)' value='6'>
        <input type='button' onclick='numBr(this)' value='7'>
        <input type='button' onclick='numBr(this)' value='8'>
        <input type='button' onclick='numBr(this)' value='9'>
    <hr>
</div>
```